# Удалить непечатаемый символ

Tags: php

Каким образом с помощью регулярного выражения на PHP удалить этот символ? Ни один из ответов в интернете, в том числе и chatGPT мне не помогли.

Важно, чтобы из строки удалился только невидимый символ. Вот один из вариантов, который рекомендовался в интернете — не сработал, невидимый символ так и остался.

```
$first_name = 'ㅤtest qwe привет ❤️';
$first_name = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $first_name);

echo $first_name;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому, что `/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u` удаляет только все непечатаемые символы из ASCII + непереносимый пробел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае перед составлением регулярного выражения для очистки текста необходимо провести анализ предмета очистки (текста), т.е. какие множества символов необходимо сохранить, а какие удалить.

Используем, например, [Конвертер символов в их числовые значения и обратно](http://wb0.ru/chrconv.php).
Находим, что искомый знак - это символ с кодом [`&#12644;`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3164) или в шестнадцатеричном виде `3164`.
Используем правила RegEx и кодируем его в `\x{3164}`, потом помещаем в выражение `'/[\x{3164}]/u'` (квадратные скобки применены для общего случая, когда может быть задано множество и/или диапазоны исключаемых символов).

```
<?php
$first_name = 'ㅤtest qwe привет ❤️';
$first_name = preg_replace('/[\x{3164}]/u', '', $first_name);

echo $first_name;
```

```
test qwe привет ❤️
```

При необходимости удаления множества символов можно воспользоваться уже существующими (заданными) Unicode-подмножествами Regex, о чем можно прочесть, например, [здесь](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). К примеру, `\p{Zs} or \p{Space_Separator}`.

Comment: Благодарю! Не подскажете, пожалуйста, каким образом узнавать так код всех подобных символов?

Comment: Например, [здесь](http://wb0.ru/chrconv.php)

Comment: спасибо огромное, лучший!

Comment: Можете помочь последний раз, пожалуйста? Есть ещё один символ и он выдаёт &#3584;&#3584;&#32;&#3584;&#3584;

Как такое исправить регуляркой?

Comment: Наверное, так: '/[\x{3164}\x{0E00}]/u', поскольку 3584 (дес.) == E00 (шестн.)

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили <3 Тут не сработало, к сожалению, а есть вообще какое-нибудь общее выражение, чтобы подобное снести? Я могу заплатить за помощь если что, просто пришлите свой контакт (tg например)

Comment: Вариант 1. Попробовать определить диапазоны допустимых символов, остальные удалять. Вариант 2. Почитать [здесь](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) или что-то подобное. Вариант 3. Определить диапазоны недопустимых символов. Вариант 4. Сочетание предыдущих вариантов.

Comment: В текущем виде ответ совершенно бесполезен для приходящих из поиска. Его надо либо дополнить, либо удалить.

Comment: @Ипатьев ваши конкретные предложения по улучшению?

Comment: Как минимум дополнить информацией из комментариев и предложить актуальный код, который хоть как-то реализует один из предложенных вариантов, а не оставляет читателю назидательную рекомендацию "ну ты сам напиши". Например оставляет русские и латинские буквы, пунктуацию и [эмодзи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470079/emoji-value-range)